# What is the difference between these 2. Changing object references and deleting

Tags: java, object, reference, variable-assignment

**Case 1:**

```
Object x = y
y = z
x = null
```

*where y and z is of the same object type.

**Case 2:**

```
y = z
```

I basically want to set y to z and delete y (set it to null). Will case 1 do this? If it does, how does that work exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Java there is no concept of explicit delete.

Objects that do not have references pointing to them are automatically deleted by the garbage collector.

Therefore `y = z;` would be enough if the object that were previously pointed by `y` has no other references pointing to it.

Case 1 does not work like you might think, `x = null;` means that `x` points to nothing, it doesn't explicitly delete the object pointed.

Here a visual representation:

[image: cases]

In red if the object has no other references, thus will be deleted by the garbage collector.

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed diagram. It helped me understand it much better!

Answer (score 3):

The first option creates a new variable `x` which ends up set to null, and it sets `y` to the same object as `z`.

The second option just sets `y` to the same object as `z`.

Neither option deletes anything. If you want to set `z` to null, you need `z = null`. If you want to set `y` to null, you need `y = null`. Setting another variable to null does not affect your other variables or the objects they reference.

When an object has *no* remaining variables referencing it, it is eligible for garbage collection.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, a variable of a certain class' type isn't an object of that class itself, it just has the potential to hold the reference to an object of that class. Think of this as the variable being able to know the address of an object, where the object "lives". With that in mind, take a look at some examples below:

```
Foo var;
```

In the example above you simply declared a variable of the type "Foo". It doesn't have a reference to any object. Attempting to call a method on it will throw a null point exception.

```
var = new Foo();
```

Here you are telling the variable var to hold a reference (the "address") that points to a newly created object of the class "Foo". That object is explicitly created by using the keyword "new". Now you can call methods on the new object.

After understanding this, it's important to know that, in Java, there is no way to explicitly delete an object. Java's **garbage collector** handles this for you. **When there are no references to an object (meaning that no variables hold a copy of the object's "address"), the garbage collector automatically deletes it.** So, basically, if you want to get rid of an object, just make sure none of your variables hold a reference to it. You can do that, for example, by setting the variable's value to *null*, like below:

```
var = null; //if no other variables hold a reference to the object created in the 2nd example, it will be deleted by the GC.
```

The answer ended up being quite long. I'm a beginner myself and I'm loving to study these things. I hope this can be of help to you as well as to any other beginners like us. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you, that was a great explanation. Gave me a better insight into how the garbage collector works.

Comment: I'm glad it helped!